# is there any way to call a variable from a specific if statement?

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, scope, gravity

ok so I need to make this program that involves the gravity constant. but i let the user decide that

```
double g;
String unit;

if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    g = 9.8;
    System.out.print(g);
    unit = "meters/s";
}
else {
    g = 32;
    System.out.print(g);
    unit = "feet/s";
}
```

and then i put it into this formula OUTSIDE of the if statement

```
double ycoord = (velo0*sinF*time)-((g)((time*time)))/2;
```

i know that the scope of the if statement ends after the last curly brace but i'm wondering if there is any way to call for one of the values of g

thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "if there is any way to call for one of the values of g"? What exactly isn't working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the above bit of code inside a method, then it's scope is restricted to that method. However you can create a class variable g and set it within your method.

```
Public Class Test {

     //g can only be accessed within this class
     //however you can access g with the following getter method
     private double g;

     public static void setG() {

          this.g = 9.5;
     }

     public static void setGWithInput(Double input) {

          this.g = input;              
     }

     public static void printG() {

          //you can access the value of g anywhere from your class
          System.out.println("Value of g is" + this.g);
     }

     //create a public getter to access the value of g form outside the class
     public double getG() {

          return this.g;
     }
}
```

Comment: I did some more research and set the original initialization of the variable to a final and that fixed my problem! thank you guys very much for taking the time to help me though

Answer (score 0):

As long as your statement containing your "formula" is within the same function/code block as the *declaration* of 'g', you can reference g as part of that statement.

You should really provide more details and describe your problem more explicitly.

Comment: I did some more research and set the original initialization of the variable to a final and that fixed my problem! thank you guys very much for taking the time to help me though